# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, error-handling

I am doing a modular programming for my nlp project in a vs code. I am facing a error of no module found.

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Text-summarization-project\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TextSummerization.pipeline.data_ingestion_stage1 import DataIngestionTrainingPipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TextSummerization'`
```

My file structre is like:

```
src
|__TextSummerization
   |__pipeline
      |__data_ingestion_stage1.py
main.py
setup.py
app.py
```

I don't understand what is a main cause of the problem here. Please help me to find out.

I check the module name and fiel path all are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 'src' directory is in your Python path. You can add it dynamically in your main.py file using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/src')
```

Comment: Should maybe mention [\_\_init\_\_.py](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories)